# Can a Portable Hole be moved after it is unfolded and laid down?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

When you lay down a *portable hole*, is it locked in place or can you slide it? Specifically I was wondering if a player could place the *hole* on the ground and then slide it halfway under a door to climb in and then out the other side?

Alternatively, could a character jump into the *hole* and have the party slide the *hole* with him in it under the door to the other side?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Good first question!

Answer (score 8):

This is a little tricky, but you might be able to pull off your tactic without answering the question.  We'll try anyway.

According to the description from the *DMG*, page 185:

> You can use an action to unfold a *portable hole* and place it on or against a solid surface, whereupon the *portable hole* creates an extradimensional hole 10 feet deep.
>
> ...You can use an action to close a *portable hole* by taking hold of the edges of the cloth and folding it up.

Nowhere in the description does it say that you can move a *portable hole* once opened, and normally, the rule is that things do what they say they can do and nothing more.  There is a further implication that the magic inherent to the cloth only allows you to open it or close it when manipulating the extradimensional space- based on the description, I imagine it works similarly to the cartoon holes in *Who Framed Roger Rabbit*, which didn't do anything until placed on a surface with a slight sucking sound.  All this adds up to a resounding **"probably not."**

**However.**

> If the hole is folded up, a creature within the hole's extradimensional space can use an action to make a DC 10 Strength check.  On a successful check, the creature forces its way out and appears within 5 feet of the *portable hole* or the creature carrying it.

It *would* be entirely possible for a character to climb into the hole, have someone fold up the hole and shove it under a door, and then force their way out on the other side.